# Python scikit-learn RandomForestClassifier access individual trees and how to save them

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest

How can I access individual trees and save/load a RandomForestClassifier object?

I just want to see the structure of each tree to determine which feature is important.  I want to save the trained classifier object in a file or database.  How to do it?

Answer (score 4):

You essentially have three questions.

**1. How to see individual trees**

You can see the individual trees using of a `RandomForestClassifier` using

```
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
rf.fit(X,y) 
trees = rf.estimators_
```

**2. Feature Importance**

For determing feature importance, your best bet is probably to use

```
rf.feature_importances_
```

This will produce an numpy array of feature importances, one per column of X, representing the relative importance of each feature.

**3. Save your model**

An easy way to save a fitted scikit-learn model or pipeline is through pickle.

```
byte_string = pickle.dumps(rf)
```

It could then be loaded using

```
rf = pickle.loads(byte_string)
```

If you have additional requirements that it should be ASCII you may want to use base64.

```
 text_model = base64.b64encode(byte_string)
```

Comment: David, are you rock-solid sure to guarrantee the complete **`RandomForestClassifier`** instance gets pickled state-fully ( `.fit()`-ed, with all class-methods ) to a **retrievable `.predict()`-able form?**

Comment: I've never had a problem with pickling scikit-learn estimators or transformers. In my example above I was able to load the pickled string and predict with it.

Comment: **Thanks David**, worth a note. I will need to re-test ( had bad troubles with trying this some years ago ). BTW - which versions do you operate on observing this? Mine were py26/py27, pickle/cPickle protocol=2.

Comment: Python 2.7.10 from anaconda. Using the standard pickle, default protocol.

Comment: **Again, thanks, David.** FYI, this year the project has turned to lovely Mike McKerns' **`dill`** workhorse ( both for "pickle" services & distributed grid processing SERialise-pushToRemoteAgent-pullFromRemoteAgent-DESerialise & ( !! ) **state-full save/restore** *the whole* localhost interpreter-session on another host ).